# Import Python variable to HTML

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x

I have an HTML page that processes Wi-Fi credentials and writes them to an interfaces file on the Raspberry Pi 3. The HTML file `post_list_three.html` is shown below

```
{% extends 'device_interfaces/base.html' %}


{% block content %}
    <h2>Static Configuration Page</h2>

    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.as_p }}
     <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

base.html is as follows

```
{% load static %}

<html>
    <body>
        <div class="page-header">
            <a href="{% url 'post_list_three' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon$
            <h1>Wi-Fi Static Configuration</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="content container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    {% block content %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

I have a Python file, `tech_scripts.py`, that writes the interfaces file and checks if the given credentials are correct to connect to the Wi-Fi. The code for checking Wi-Fi connection is called as a function in `tech_scripts.py` and its snippet is below.

```
def CheckConnection():
    ps = subprocess.Popen(['iwconfig'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(('grep', 'ESSID'), stdin=ps.stdout).decode()
        status = output.split('ESSID:')[1].split('/')[0]
        if status == 'off':
            print("Wi-Fi not connected")
            return False
        else:
            print("Wi-Fi connected")
           return True
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        # grep did not match any lines
       print("No wireless networks connected")
       return False
```

I want to retrieve what the above function returns(i.e True or False) and use those in the `post_list_three.html` file above.

How do i import what this function returns into the HTML file so that i can manipulate the page into reloading if the credentials are not correct(i.e the function returns False)?

Edit,

the views.py below

```
import subprocess
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import ConfigInfo
from .forms import ConfigInfoForm

def post_list_three(request):
    from .models import ConfigInfo
    ConfigInfo.objects.all().delete()
    if request.method =="POST":
       form =ConfigInfoForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           ConfigInfo=form.save(commit=False)
           ConfigInfo.save()
           subprocess.Popen(["python3", "/home/pi/tutorial/device_interfaces/tech_scripts.py","-m"])
    else:
        form=ConfigInfoForm()
    return render(request, 'device_interfaces/post_edit.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Where is your view? What does the form do?

Comment: I added the views above. The form basically takes info from a django model object and writes that info to the interfaces file in the raspberry pi

Comment: I can't really understand what is going on here. Why are you calling tech_scripts.py via subprocess? Why don't you import it and call CheckConnection directly?

Comment: Im calling tech_scripts via subprocess because i want it to run inside views in that function, i.e when the webpage is opened

Comment: What? That doesn't make sense at all. It's called on POST anyway. But that doesn't explain why you would run it via subprocess rather than importing and calling it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman importing it would  cause another problem(Import Error). The subprocess is a workaround

Comment: Why would there be an import error? Sounds like you should fix that rather than using a workaround that gets in the way of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Okay, let me do that and try to proceed with what i need to do. Thanks